# Does TypeScript allow a type alias to specify generics?

Tags: function, typescript, generics, type-alias

I would like to be able to alias a very generic function and specify *part* of the generic parameters, thus creating a less generic version of the same function. Something like the following:

```
function veryGeneric<X, Y>(someParam: Y): { result: X } {
  // ...
}

type LessGeneric = typeof veryGeneric<X, string>
const lessGeneric: LessGeneric = veryGeneric
```

Where I would want the `lessGeneric` function to essentially be typed as:

```
function lessGeneric<X>(someParam: string): { result: X } {
  // ...
}
```

Is this possible in any way?

I know I could create a wrapper function, but I would prefer to not have to specify the parameter typings again (and not having to pay the overhead of another function call, even if it’s tiny, would be a bonus).

---

Here’s the real example I’m dealing with. Given a function declaration (from [react-tracking](https://github.com/alloy/DefinitelyTyped/blob/react-tracking/types/react-tracking/index.d.ts#L60)) like the following:

```
declare function track<T = {}, P = {}>(trackingInfo?: TrackingInfo<T, P>, options?: Options<Partial<T>>): Decorator
```

I want to be able to define an alias that specifies the `trackingInfo` parameter’s typing but leaves `P` generic. i.e. I want an alias that’s essentially typed as:

```
interface ValidAnalyticsEntries {
  page: string
  action: string
}

declare function trackSpecificToOurAnalyticsSchema<P = {}>(trackingInfo?: TrackingInfo<ValidAnalyticsEntries, P>, options?: Options<Partial<ValidAnalyticsEntries>>): Decorator
```

Comment: What's the point here? There's no use of the `X` generic constraint, why is it there? Please share your real code

Comment: I don’t believe there’s a need to know what `X` does for this example, I’ve added a simple illustration, though.

Comment: You can get better help if you describe your problem better, and in this case it's not well explained.  There's no need to put `X` as a generic constraint if you're only using it in the function and it's not a parameter or the return type.

Comment: I understand that, but was under the impression that the `// ...` part made it clear that there are details that are unrelated to the question at hand. I have now added the real example.

Comment: Will you use the same function (`track`) or are you actually implementing `trackSpecificToOurAnalyticsSchema`?

Comment: The `trackSpecificToOurAnalyticsSchema` constant should hold a reference to the same function object as `track`, so it will be the same function, but in our code I would use the `trackSpecificToOurAnalyticsSchema` constant to make use of the specific typing. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To define generic type alias you can define an interface describing your function signature:

```
interface VeryGeneric<X, Y> {
    (someParam: Y): { result: X };
}

type Foo = { foo: number };
type LessGeneric<X = Foo> = VeryGeneric<X, string>;

const lessGeneric: LessGeneric = veryGeneric;
```

Comment: Thanks! I still needed to use a wrapper function to be able to let the user of the less generic version specify `X`, but at least the consumer could re-use the interface and generate functions with custom defaults. You can find those examples here https://github.com/artsy/reaction/blob/7bc53212a5898dd02b5e49e258c932c3768d12f0/src/utils/track.ts

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
const lessGeneric: <X>(someParam: string) => { result: X } = veryGeneric;
```

I'm just spelling out the desired type of `lessGeneric` without trying to force TypeScript to convert the type of `veryGeneric` to the type of `lessGeneric` first.  There's no wrapper function, though.

Does this work for you?  If not, please add more detail to your use case and example.  Specifically, the `X` parameter is almost impossible to implement (how can the implementation get its hands on a value of type `X`) and the `Y` parameter is doing next to nothing (the `someParam` argument is of type `Y`, but nothing else is using `Y`, so you might as well just declare `someParam` to be of type `any` and not use `Y`).

Hope that helps; good luck!

---

EDIT: My suggestion for the real example looks like:

```
const trackSpecificToOurAnalyticsSchema: <P = {}>(
  trackingInfo?: TrackingInfo<ValidAnalyticsEntries, P>,
  options?: Options<Partial<ValidAnalyticsEntries>>)
  => Decorator = track;
```

Or, abstracting away from `ValidAnalyticsEntries`:

```
type PartiallySpecifiedTrack<T = {}> = <P = {}>(
  trackingInfo?: TrackingInfo<T, P>,
  options?: Options<Partial<T>>)
  => Decorator

const trackSpecificToOurAnalyticsSchema: 
  PartiallySpecifiedTrack<ValidAnalyticsEntries> = track;
```

Note that in all these cases you still have to write out function signature at least two times in total: once when you define the fully generic `track()`, and once to define `PartiallySpecifiedTrack`.  But you can re-use `PartiallySpecifiedTrack` with different values for `T` if you want:

```
const anotherTrack: PartiallySpecifiedTrack<{ foo: string }> = track;
declare const trackingInfo: TrackingInfo<{ foo: string }, {bar: number}>
anotherTrack(trackingInfo); // okay
```

Okay, that's the best I can do.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Indeed there’s no wrapper function, so that’s definitely a step up, but my foremost reason is that I don’t want to spell out all the parameters again.

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't yet found anything that less verbose as my answer above.